# SOAP REQUEST on PHP Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: php, soap, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to figure out how to get the right response from Multidimensional array in a SOAP request.

In fact, I would like to be able to Submit a "VAT" number and get the `MULTISCORE` value

functions.php

```
<?php

function score ($name)
{
    $details=array(

                array(
                VAT=>"BE0422370068",
                COMPANY=>"DEXIA",
                MULTISCORE=>25,
                CITY=>"HASSELT"
                )
                /*
                array(
                VAT=>"BE0402607507",
                COMPANY=>"SCANIA",
                MULTISCORE=>50,
                CITY=>"BRUSSEL"
                ),

                array(
                VAT=>"BE0446140711",
                COMPANY=>"DELHAIZE",
                MULTISCORE=>50,
                CITY=>"GENT"
                )
                */
                );

    foreach($details as $va=>$var) //BTW
    {
        foreach($va as $co=>$cor) //COMPANY
        {
            foreach($co as $mu=$mur) //MULTISCORE
            {
                foreach($mu as $ci=<$cir) //CITY
                {
        if($name==$va) //If VAT exist
            $score=$mur; //Show MULTISCORE value
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $score;
}
?>
```

These functions are called from following PHP request
Client.php

```
<?php
require 'lib/nusoap.php';

$client = new nusoap_client("http://localhost:8080/service.php?wsdl");

if (isset($_POST["cia"]))

{
    $cia_name = $_POST["cia"];

}

if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Scania Finance GRAYDON</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
Company: <input type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" name="cia"><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php

} else {

    $response = $client->call('score',array("name"=>"$cia_name"));

    if (empty($response))

        echo "Please go <b>'Back'</b> and enter Company name";

    else 

        echo "GRAYDON - MultiScore of Company $cia_name is equal to <b>".$response."</b></br></br>";

if ($response < '30'){
    echo "SORRY, Graydon MultiScore is less than 30!";
} elseif ($response < '60'){
    echo "CAN BE DISCUSSED, Graydon MultiScore is between 30 and 60, the visit of a Financial Salesman is needed!";
} else {
    echo "GREAT, Graydon MultiScore is greater than 60, we can do Business together!";
}
}
?>
</body>
```

I can't find the way to call the right Array values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things.

1) in your function.php  file write this line:-

```
$score = $details[$key];

return $score;
```

2) In your client.php file

$response is now Array so you need to print it via

```
print_r($response);
```

Now you can get MULTISCORE by `$response['MULTISCORE']` and COMPANY NAME by `$response['COMPANY']`;

**Note**:- You wrote `echo $response` so you got only `"Array"` print.

**Suggestion**:- You should ON [Error Reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) in developement mode otherwise you cannot debug code properly.

Write this line as:-

```
echo "GRAYDON - MultiScore of VAT ".$vat_num." is equal to <b>".$response['MULTISCORE']."</b></br></br>";
```

check new condion like this:-

```
if($response['MULTISCORE'] < '30'){
   // your code
}
```

if you want company name then,

print company name:-

```
echo $response['COMPANY'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run foreach loop in this case. If you simply want MULTISCORE by submitting VAT value then it is very easy by below way:

refer [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
    function score ($name)
    {

        $details=array(

                    array(
                    'VAT'=>"BE0422370068",
                    'COMPANY'=>"DEXIA",
                    'MULTISCORE'=>25,
                    'CITY'=>"HASSELT"
                    )
                    /*
                    array(
                    'VAT'=>"BE0402607507",
                    COMPANY=>"SCANIA",
                    MULTISCORE=>50,
                    CITY=>"BRUSSEL"
                    ),

                    array(
                    VAT=>"BE0446140711",
                    COMPANY=>"DELHAIZE",
                    MULTISCORE=>50,
                    CITY=>"GENT"
                    )
                    */
                    );

    $key = array_search($name, array_column($details, 'VAT'));
   // $key = array_search('BE0402607507', array_column($details, 'VAT'));   
    $score = $details[$key]['MULTISCORE'];    
    return $score;

    }
```

if you want all array values by submitting VAT then you need to write following line:-

```
$score = $details[$key]; 
return $score;
```

Now you will get company name by `echo $score['COMPANY'];` and multiscore by `echo $score['MULTISCORE'];`

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Great! I guess I need more PHP learning sessions! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, anyway, I can't get it. As already said, tried several options as you asked but can't get the value only returns "Array".

For people are looking for how to retrieve one value of a multidimensional array using a SOAP request, to test it use XAMPP, here my work files on a PHPSOAP.zip

workfiles:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-pCOHYZNf6COFNLdFV5RkpITGM/view?usp=sharing

Ravi Hirani thank you for your help!